# Working with CLI and missing my namespace classes inside

Tags: wp-cli

I'm very new to WordPress development. I hit this error when i developering my own class and namespace to do the life easier to reuse my code on cross of platforms/frameworks.

I have added my CLI command like this

```bash
wp product:sync
```

And when i run my CLI command whitout my class its run as it shut, I can get access to the internel WordPress functions did not working.

CLI_Controller.php

```php
<?php

namespace WMS\Controllers;

use WMS\Controllers\CLI\CLI_Products;

class CLI
{
    function init()
    {
        add_action('cli_init', function () {
            $product_cli = new CLI_Products();

            \WP_CLI::add_command('product:sync', $product_cli->execute());
            \WP_CLI::add_command('stock:sync', $product_cli->hello_world());
            \WP_CLI::add_command('order:sync', $product_cli->hello_world());
        });
    }
}
```

Product_Controller.php

```php
<?php

namespace WMS\Controllers\CLI;

use WMS\Controllers\WMSApi\APIService\Items;

class CLI_Products
{
    public function hello_world()
    {
        \WP_CLI::line('Hello World!');
    }

    function execute()
    {
        $api_items = new Items();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 10
        );

        $loop = new \WP_Query($args);
        while ($loop->have_posts()) {
            $loop->the_post();
            global $product;

            if ($product->get_sku()) {
                $item = [
                    'sku' => $product->get_sku(),
                    'description' => get_the_title()
                ];

                print_r($item);
            } else {
                echo 'Product missing SKU number';
            }
        }

        $items->import($item);
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
```

So when I run this command its giving this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
> 'WMS\Controllers\WMSApi\APIService\Items' not found in
> /var/www/frontend/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-woocommerce-plugin/src/Controllers/CLI/Product_Controller.php:16
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/frontend/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-woocommerce-plugin/src/Controllers/CLI_Controller.php(14):
> WMS\Controllers\CLI\CLI_Products->execute()

So its look like the main file did not load success, is there a way or work a round to load custom class/namespaces inside my CLI commands?

Comment: You’re not importing a file that contains that missing class. Are you using an autoloader?

Comment: Its including in my plugin file, there are autoloading, I can access for the class and namespaces in normal way but not inside the CLI so its pretty weird.

Comment: are you sure that's how `add_command` is supposed to work? It's expecting a `callable` value the same way `add_filter` or `add_action` works but that's not what you're giving it, you're not giving it something to call, it's directly calling them which is very wrong, this usage is incorrect. Also you should never modify other plugins to make changes, all those changes will be destroyed when the plugin gets updated

Comment: Mabey I did it wrong, I'm build a custom plugin, and inside here I need a CLI command to work with, the problem is I can't get access to the code normally but not  inside the CLI I have created. So I need a way to get access to my own code classes inside a CLI command as i can share with the rest of my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, and I discover I missing a "vendor" folder in my root of the plugin and inside composer.json i missing a auto-loader of classes.

So what there fix my issue is update my composer.json file and then run a composer install command after inside my plugin folder.

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "WMS\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

So my CLI code work as default, its was a configuration error from my side.